# Optimizing while using std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, sfinae

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N> void bar() { std::cout << "bar<" << N << ">() called.\n"; }
template <std::size_t N> void hit() { std::cout << "hit<" << N << ">() called.\n"; }

template <typename T> struct evaluate : std::bool_constant<std::is_integral_v<T>> {
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof(T);  // Simplified for illustration only.
};

void foo() { }

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!evaluate<T>::value> foo (const T&, const Args&...);

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<evaluate<T>::value> foo (const T&, const Args&... args) {
    bar<evaluate<T>::size>();
    // Do whatever.
    foo(args...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!evaluate<T>::value> foo (const T&, const Args&... args) {
    hit<evaluate<T>::size>();
    // Do whatever, but different from the previous foo overload.
    foo(args...);
}

int main() {
    foo (5, "hello", true);
}


Output:
bar<4>() called.
hit<6>() called.
bar<1>() called.
```

How to rewrite the above so that `evaluate<T>` needs only be computed once instead of twice with each foo iteration?

Comment: `evaluate<T>` is a template. It's specialized once per argument `T` and reused subsequently.

Comment: Ok, I thought `evaluate<T>` was computed twice.  But how would you make it appear only once (without using macros)?  We are supposed to avoid repetition in code anyways.

Comment: `evaluate<T>::value` is a constant like any other. You could try to store it in another constant, but then you would need a different one for each `T`, which implies you would need to store that constant in a template of it's own, which brings you back to square one. There is also no `else` equivalent for `std::enable_if`. You just another `enable_if` with the opposite condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe like this one:

```
template <std::size_t N> void bar() { std::cout << "bar<" << N << ">() called.\n"; }
template <std::size_t N> void hit() { std::cout << "hit<" << N << ">() called.\n"; }

template <typename T>  
struct evaluate : std::bool_constant<std::is_integral_v<T>> 
{   
    static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof(T);  // Simplified for illustration only.
};  

void foo() { } 

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo( const T&, const Args&... args) 
{   
    using X = evaluate<T>;

    if constexpr ( X::value )
    {   
        bar<X::size>();
    }   
    else
    {   
        hit<X::size>();
    }   

    foo( args... );
}   


int main() {
    foo (5, "hello", true);
}
```

It "calls" only once `evaluate<T>`, which is not important but maybe easier to read. That all the template code is only used during instantiation makes it only a matter of taste.

As you mention `c++17` you can use `constexpr if` to get rid of SFINAE at all in your example. This makes it also possible to reuse common lines of code in both variants of foo which is quite nice. The executable will not be much different you can believe, but the maintainability is much better I think!

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, I thought evaluate was computed twice. But how would you make it appear only once (without using macros)? We are supposed to avoid repetition in code anyways

You can try to save it as a additional template parameter with default value

Something as

```
template <typename T, typename... Args, typename E = evaluate<T>>
std::enable_if_t<!E::value> foo (const T&, const Args&...);

template <typename T, typename... Args, typename E = evaluate<T>>
std::enable_if_t<E::value> foo (const T&, const Args&... args)
 {
   bar<E::size>();
   // Do whatever.
   foo(args...);
 }

template <typename T, typename ... Args, typename E>
std::enable_if_t<!E::value> foo (const T&, const Args&... args)
 {
   hit<E::size>();
   // Do whatever, but different from the previous foo overload.
   foo(args...);
 }
```